# Difference between "for a long time" and "long time"

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-perfect, word-order, prepositional-phrases, time

For the following sentences:

- Alex has been my friend *for* a long time.
- Alex has been a long time friend of mine.

Do both of these sentences imply that "Alex" is still my friend?

Comment: Yes, I think they are correct with the same meaning.

Comment: Many would put a hyphen in the term "long time" when it is used adjectively: _Alex has been a long-time friend of mine_. [Behold the ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+long+time+friend%2C+a+long-time+friend&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: I am sure though there must be a difference if I say "Alex has been a good friend" vs. "Alex has been a good friend for a long time" I think the first sentence imply that Alex is no longer a friend. So, why don't the above two sentences in question aren't similar?

Comment: @user92131: Using Present Perfect in something like *Alex has been a good friend* simply implies some strong connection to time of speaking. The connection could just as well be *contrastive* (he's no longer a good friend), rather than a matter of straightforward *continuity* (he was a good friend in the past, and he still is now). If the full context doesn't make it obvious, and you specifically want to convey that he's no longer a good friend, you'd use something more explicit, such as *He **was** a good friend*.

Comment: @Fumble - Or _Alex **had** been a good friend_. Changing _has_ to _had_ creates the impression that the friendship may no longer be in tact.

Comment: @user92131 - Why are you sure there must be a difference?  Was there a book or a teacher that told you there was a difference?  (By the way, we don't say "Why don't they aren't similar" - *to be* doesn't take *do* when you make a question; it's just "Why aren't they similar")

Comment: @stangdon: Yes, well because I learned this fact which says that if you specify a duration with 'for' or 'since' it means a continuation of event in past to present. Consider: "I have lived in France" and "I have lived in France for 2 years". The latter suggests that you are still in France. (Yes, that was my careless mistake to use double negatives in sentence, thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is fine, but the second sentence is not very idiomatic. The verb "has been" is usually followed by an expression describing a time interval, unless the interval is already understood by both parties to the conversation. The phrase "a long-time friend of mine" does not directly express a time interval, even though it implies one. I would rephrase the second sentence as

- Alex is a long-time friend of mine. (OK, but less common)
- Alex is an old friend of mine. (quite common)
- Alex and I are old friends. (concise, but less emphasis on time passing)